# Как правильно сохранить пришедший с сервера файл retrofit android?

Tags: android, retrofit

Я создаю приложение которое посылает разные запросы на сервер при помощи `retrofit`. Одним из таких запросов есть запрос на прикрепленный к письму файл. Вот я прописал этот запрос в интерфейсе:

```
Call<FileData> getAttach(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Path("id") Integer id, @Path("attach_file_name") String file_name, @Query("type") int type);
```

Вот класс `FileData` который используется в запросе:

```
public class FileData {
    @SerializedName("size")
    @Expose
    private double size;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public FileData(double size, String name) {
        this.size = size;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getSize() {
        return Math.round(size * 100.0) / 100.0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

и дальше вот я шлю запрос в классе:

```
mAPIService.getAttach("Bearer " + access_token, id, name, ty_pe).enqueue(new Callback<FileData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<FileData> call, @NonNull Response<FileData> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<FileData> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

и вот несколько примеров как мне приходит в ответе прикрепленный файл:

картинка:

```
 200 OK https://сервер/v1/message/1303758/attachment/575b3981-4372-4104-98f3-a9eee386a0d5.jpg?type=1 (215ms)
        Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 10:18:51 GMT
        Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
        Content-Length: 107625
        Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="575b3981-4372-4104-98f3-a9eee386a0d5.jpg"
        P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"
    08-27 11:17:01.040 D: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

или вот пустой текстовый документ:

```
200 OK https://сервер/v1/message/1303651/attachment/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.txt?type=1 (224ms)
    Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 10:22:27 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Новый текстовый документ.txt"
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

если в документе например есть какой-то текст, то в ответе соответственно приходит тот текст который есть в документе.

Я сейчас вот читаю [такую](https://devcolibri.com/java-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/) статью, но здесь сохраняют текст в документ. Я не могу понять как сохранять любой формат дока а не только текст. Картинку например, или архив (за архив я вообще не понимаю как это будет происходить), ссылку html. Название худо-бедно можно вытащить из запроса, или из ответа, размер необязательно, но вот как создать новый файл с нужным мне расширением и с правильным содержимым. Если кто-то занимался подобного рода разработкой, то я буду очень благодарен за полезные советы и любую информацию.

### UPDATE

```
 public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    File file = new File("Download", name);
                    if (writeToFile(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()), file)) {
                        // файл записан, работаем дальше
                        Toast.makeText(MessageShow.this, "File was downloaded!!)))", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Ой чёй-то не то,
                        // может разрешения надо было запросить???
                        // давай смотреть логи
                        // и извиняться юзеру :(
                    }
                }
            }
```

вот что в логах я увидел:

```
08-29 13:50:38.022 W: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Download/index.html (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.ActionsMessages.MessageShow.writeToFile(MessageShow.java:253)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.ActionsMessages.MessageShow.access$300(MessageShow.java:47)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.ActionsMessages.MessageShow$3.onResponse(MessageShow.java:229)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

может создавать новую директорию для файлов, потому-что указанная директория существует, но там ничего нету.

Comment: Нужно не просто имя папки а весь путь к ней в файловой системе. Почитайте гайд по сохранению файлов: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: а какие permission нужны кроме чтения и записи external_storage? а то я вроде получил папку но теперь пишет что `permission denied`. `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Новый текстовый документ.txt (Permission denied)`

Comment: Начиная с Android 6.0 (API level 23) нужно запрашивать ["опасные"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups) разрешения в коде: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#make-the-request . Ответ по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874725/11515

Comment: что-то я не очень понял, опасные это типа доступ к контактам? зачем моему приложению этот доступ, к примеру...

Comment: Доступ к external storage тоже относится к опасным: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups

Comment: так я дал доступ, не могу понять почему при разрешении все равно не качает, или нужно что-бы пользователь дал разрешение вручную?

Comment: Ну так о том и речь. Я Вам дал ссылку на ответ, где по русски всё написано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874725/11515

Comment: упс, не увидел ее) сейчас посмотрю

Comment: не получается( сейчас создам новый вопрос наверное, потому-что все сделал так как на сайте, а все-равно в папке  файла нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модель в этом запросе не нужна - нам нужен сырой поток байтов. Его можно получить в дефолтном `ResponseBody`. Меняем апи-метод:

```
@Headers({"Content-type:application/json"})
@GET("/v1/message/{id}/attachment/{attach_file_name}")
Call<ResponseBody> getAttach(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Path("id") Integer id, @Path("attach_file_name") String file_name, @Query("type") int type);
```

---

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            File file = ...;
            if (writeToFile(response.body(), file)) {
                // файл записан, работаем дальше
            } else {
                // Ой чёй-то не то,
                // может разрешения надо было запросить???
                // давай смотреть логи
                // и извиняться юзеру :(
            }
        } else {
            // не забываем проверять ответ сервера
            // на неудачный запрос
        }
    }
```

Пишем в файл (улучшить реализацию не возбраняется):

```
private boolean writeToFile(ResponseBody body, File file) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = body.byteStream();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;

        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } cath(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } cath(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: я не очень понимаю, что в случае удачного запроса `File file = ...;` здесь должно быть, присвоить может `response.body`?

Comment: Вы должны указать файл, в который нужно сохранить

Comment: то есть здесь нужно создавать новый файл с нужным мне расширением и названием?

Comment: Да, в нужной папке, с нужным именем и расширением. Типа `new File(myDir, myNameDotExt);`. Папка должна существовать (быть создана при необходимости) до начала записи.

Comment: все таки не очень понятно, ведь имя файла нужно как-то получить, и расширение тоже, в модели я хоть как-то мог это получить, а из `response.body()` вроде никак не вытаскивается + `if (writeToFile(body, file))` что имеется в виду под переменной `body`?

Comment: сейчас добавлю в вопрос последнюю версию кода, потому-что при попытке загрузить файл вроде ошибки нету, но почему-то пишет что нету указанной директории или файла