# Помогите решить ошибку при загрузке файлов с сервера android retrofit

Tags: android

В своем приложении я мне нужно сделать функцию загрузки файла с сервера, не принципиально какого именно формата - картинка, архив или просто txt файл. Вот мой предыдущий вопрос - [Как правильно сохранить пришедший с сервера файл retrofit android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873938/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-retrofit-android). После продолжительных поисков я вроде-как нашел [способ](http://www.riptutorial.com/android/example/14961/download-a-file-from-server-using-retrofit2) как загрузить файл. Но у меня не получается использовать мой `responce.body()` в функции которую предлагают для загрузки файла. Надеюсь кто-то найдет у меня ошибку и поможет решить эту проблему.

Comment: Вам нужно его просто скачать и положить в какую-то директорию?

Comment: Замените свою модель `FileData` на дефолтный `ResponseBody` - в этом запросе модель не нужна. И тогда должно получиться.

Comment: то есть и в интерфейсе тоже нужно поменять на `ResponseBody`? просто если поменять и в интерфейсе, и дальше прописать функцию из примера, то загрузка не начинается, может на эмуляторе не работает загрузка?

Comment: А логи смотрели? Ответ сервера проверяли?

Comment: в логах все ок, запрос нормальный, ответ тоже, но на эмуляторе загрузка не стартует, эмулятор вообще поддерживает функцию загрузки какой-то?